# how to add delay for a number of method calls and to start second method call only when first one finishes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a number of methods that insert data into database table.These methods are called one after the other. While the insertion process in on, I want my UI to show appropriate message.

eg-

```
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"food"]];
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZUSDA_FOODS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"usda_food"]]
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZDAILY_MENU_RECIPE_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"daily_menu_recipe"]];
```

So, when I say

```
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"food"]];
```

label on ui must show 'Updating Added Food Items...'

then when next line comes

```
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZUSDA_FOODS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"usda_food"]];
```

label should read as 'Updating Usda Food' and so on.

I want the text on label to remain at least for a second. I have used 'dispatch_after' but still not able to get the desired effect.

Is there  a way to insert delays between method calls and also to make sure that second method is called only when first one is completed.

Comment: Using completion blocks might help.

Comment: write custom functions, and call next function in that function

Comment: Why make the user wait? Just do it and tell them it's done?

Comment: @byJeevan how to use completion blocks for so many method calls. Plz suggest.

Comment: Add a method to your database manager to take multiple items and handle the timing there.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of completion block :)
change your method to take a completion block as an arguement and once done with the job execute the completion block :) and in completion block start the next method call :)

You can modify your method signature as follow

```
-(void)insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:(NSData *)data andCompletionBlock:(void (^)())completionBlock{
    //do whatever you want to do here
    //once done simply say
    completionBlock();
}
```

and you can call this method as :)

```
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"food"] andCompletionBlock:^{
    //call next method
    //[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZUSDA_FOODS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"usda_food"] andCompletionBlock:^{
    }];
}];
```

And in case you dont wanna send any completion block simply pass nil :)
But in that case dont forget to add the check as `if(completionBlock)` before calling `completionBlock()` app will crash in case it is passed as nil :)

on a second thought :)

if your method `insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:` is synchronous :) you can change the label directly like

```
yourLabel.text = @"Updating Added Food Items...";
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"food"]];
yourLabel.text = @"Doing something else ...";
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZUSDA_FOODS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"usda_food"]];
yourLabel.text = @"Doing something else again...";
[dbManager insertIntoTable_ZDAILY_MENU_RECIPE_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"daily_menu_recipe"]];
```

No need of any delay or completion block here buddy :)

Finally if your concern is methods are executing much faster and label wont even appear for a fraction of a second and you intentionally want to add a delay between each method :)

```
-(void)insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:(NSData *)data andCompletionBlock:(void (^)())completionBlock{
        //do whatever you want to do here
        //once done simply say
        double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         completionBlock();
    });
 }
```

Hope my answer helped you :) Happy coding :)

Comment: It will definately work for say 2 or 3 methods but here i have about 12 method calls. I would end up making a completion block inside a completion block inside a completion block...

Comment: @mars : If close coupling is ok for you then call directly the next method at the end of each method like -(void)insertIntoTable_ZADDED_FOOD_ITEMS_WithData:(NSData *)data{ //do whatever you want at the end call next method [dbManager insertIntoTable_ZUSDA_FOODS_WithData:[resultObj objectForKey:@"usda_food"]] }

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) its a well known design pattern, basically its a list and each item has state, when one finishes the next one starts.

this case will allow you to not have a completion block inside a completion block inside a completion block.

Comment: can u plz give me an easy example on objective c

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful for what you required.I did this successfully.

```
- (void)button_circleBusy:(id)sender {
    firstButton.enabled = NO;
    // 60 milliseconds is .06 seconds
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.06 target:self selector:@selector(goToSecondButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)goToSecondButton:(id)sender {
    firstButton.enabled = YES;
    secondButton.enabled = NO;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.06 target:self selector:@selector(goToThirdButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

I hope it will work for you also!!

Answer (score -1):

When you are not running you function in background then it should call one by one (after first finish). You don't need to bother about completion of first then start next.
And if you want to show message notification to hold for a sec on your screen then remove label with delay about a sec. 
You can also delay your method call for a sec and so.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeMessageLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Here "afterDelay" is responsible to make a pause for that particular method which is declared inside but compiler will move for further line execution.

Comment: Use hard-coded delays only if you have absolutely no choice. In almost all cases – like in this one – you have a choice.

Comment: what if this takes an arbitrary time to complete: sometimes 1 second sometimes 5 seconds? -- what if you have no control over how long it takes to complete?